# Laravel remember logged in user was set default

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4.2. I don't know what wrong with my code that cause it remember logged in user even i set to false in attempt function. Could anyone help me?

```
public function login()
    {
        //
        $input['username']=Input::get("username", "");
        $input['password']=Input::get("password", "");
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $input['username'], 'password' => $input['password']), false))
        {
             return Redirect::to('/');
            //return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
        }else{
            $messages="Incorrect username or password!";
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('messages', $messages);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you making sure to log out the user with `Auth::logout();` before testing a login event? Or are you just continuing to attempt login() when the user is already logged in?

Comment: thanks. I found the solution from @nbin's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expire session on Browser close set

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

on `app/config/session.php` file

For remember me- default is false. When you set it true, It is supposed to create a new session if one doesn't exist (i.e. it has expired).

So in normal case, after certain time your session expires. but if `'expire_on_close'` is true you will get your job done.